# Can two weak coherent EM beams arriving from different positions cancel out at a meeting point?

Tags: photons, interference

If two weak EM beams consist of waves with an irregular distribution of light quanta does it mean that if that photons are not uniformly distributed in a wave regarding the time when they arrive and hit the meeting point that in that case they can't cancel out? If this is very hard to understand then I will ask this way: if single photons of two different beams don't arrive at the same moment at a beams meeting point how they should cancel out?

Comment: If the beams are *coherent*, it means they are regular in space and time, whereas the distribution of photons is a *coherent state* - it is not irregular.

Comment: @Vadim Can a wave be separated from a single photon as two complements so a photon be thought of as a particle traveling with the help of the wave?In the case of a double slit it can be detected at only one location but that location is more probable where the waves are in more or less  constructive interference...

Comment: I guess, your intention is that it is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll start with the end of your questions.

> If single photons of two different beams (<s>don't</s>) arrive at the same moment at a beams meeting point how they should cancel out?

They will not cancel each other out. Because, where will the energy content go? The observation of the collision of two single photons is infinitesimal. For a beam, even if there were a rare deflection of the colliding photons, the observation shows only the undisturbed beams. However, it would be a nice experiment to prove or disprove the number of incidents.

> if ... photons are not uniformly distributed in a wave regarding the time

Photons are never evenly distributed. Simply because there is no such source. And - in addition - only in very limited cases you get an EM *wave* worthy of the name.

A thermal source, be it a light bulb or even you, emits (and receives) zillions of photons at any given time. The photons come from excited electrons. Even if photons are excited and relaxing at the same time, their position relative to the meeting point is different. And the number of excited/relaxing photons varies over time.

To obtain (and measure) a wave, you have only one option. An alternating current source and an antenna rod. By accelerating the skin electrons in the rod, all in the same direction, the electrons periodically emit polarized photons. You can measure this changing intensity, and this is how a radio receiver works.

Even for such an EM wave it is impossible to neutralize the wave. Otherwise - instead of stealth technology, which attenuates the incoming concerted photons - the enemy radar could be neutralized by its own radar.